# Why is my PHP short-code printing text instead of performing function when trying to connect to MYSQL database on Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, code-snippets

I'm trying to display a table from my MYSQL database on a website I'm creating on Wordpress. I'm using the code shown in the code block. This code is within a PHP short-code snippet and added to a Wordpress widget. Once I get past the ">" of `<your-MySQL-database-password>`, the short-code seems to screw up, and starts to print the text of the code as opposed to actually making the connection. The text that prints is:

, ,'', 'Connect'); if (!$conn){ echo 'Connection error:
mysqli_connect_error(;}?>

When I delete the ">" at the end of `<your-MySQL-database-password>` all of the printed text disappears except for the `, , at the very beginning.

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect(
        <location-of-your-database>, 
        <your-MySQL-database-username>, 
        '<your-MySQL-database-password>',
        'Connect');
    if(!$conn){
        echo 'Connection error: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

I suspect if I had a better fundamental knowledge of PHP I could figure this one out pretty easily.

1. Writing the text into the short-code and skipping the snippet
2. Creating the snippet and entering the snippet identifier into the short-code block (same result as 1.)
3. Deleting characters to see what's effecting the rest of the code.
4. Looked up to see what issues people have with snippets/shortcode on Wordpress

Comment: How are you executing this PHP code?

Comment: `<location-of-your-database>` and `<your-MySQL-database-username>` should be surrounded by quotes. Also, I don't think you need the `<` and `>` symbols; they are usually used to indicate an actual value should appear there, not the literal text shown.

Answer (score 0):

This might helps

```php
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","your-db_username","your-db_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}
?>
```